# In The Walking Dead, why did Ron Anderson try to kill Carl?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In *The Walking Dead*, why did Ron Anderson try to kill Carl? When lots of zombies flew into Alexandria because of Negan, Carl hid in the house that Ron and the others stayed in. After that Ron tried to kill him. Finally, Ron shoots Carl while moving from the house. Michonne killed Ron. I don't understand. Why did Ron have bad impressions for Carl?

Answer (score 1):

Carl told him, that his father was an asshole:

> your dad was an asshole

Plus, Rick (Carl's Father), killed Pete (Ron's Father) in "Conquer" (TWD, S5E16).

Answer (score 0):

Because Rick had killed Ron’s father and then Carl rubbed salt in the would by calling his (Ron’s) father an A-hole. It was revenge.

Answer (score 0):

He was felt that Carl was trying to "steal his girlfriend" Enid. He also was angry at Rick for killing his father, and this anger transferred to Carl somewhat, especially after Carl insulted his father.

When he finally shoots Carl, he was actually aiming for Rick (he blamed Rick for the death of his brother and mother), but Michonne's stabbing throws off his aim.

Also, the walkers got in because of the Wolves, not the Saviors/Negan.

Answer (score -1):

Everyone is saying it's "because carl called his dad an asshole etc-" but i think ron is angry. First its carl and enid. I think he is getting jealous between them. I also think he is just jealous of carl ,because he knows more things and how to survive like when he asked rick to shoot and carl was there they were talking about an handgun and carl said it was the easiest one he gave him a mad stare. Umm. and he holds  grudge againts carl because yes rick killed his dad. and also carl said rons dad was an asshole after ron tried to kill him. Im also like 99% sure ron was trying to kill rick when they was outside but than michonne ya know stabbed him made ron flinch his arm and accidently shoot carls eye out.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You seem to be mostly agreeing with the existing answers, though it's hard to follow your argument.  Please clean this up by removing extraneous bits, like the dynamic between Ron and Rick and making your argument about Carl and Ron more clear.  Try using shorter sentences, and split different thoughts into separate paragraphs.

Comment: umm no dur i am agreeing with them just more reasons and more eexamples to explain so like- and no thanks sis my typing is perfection so shoo sis